# Compare the contents of file1 and file2 and output the result

Tags: batch-file

Batch file that retrieves the string of `file1` from `file2`

file1.txt

```
aaa.dll
ccc.dll
ddd.sys
```

file2.txt

```
aaa.dll=c:\windows\aaa.dll
bbb.dll=c:\windows\bbb.dll
ccc.dll=c:\windows\system32\ccc.dll
ddd.sys=c:\windows\system32\drivers\ddd.sys
eee.log=c:\windows\debug\wia\eee.log
```

expected result

```
c:\windows\aaa.dll
c:\windows\system32\ccc.dll
c:\windows\system32\drivers\ddd.sys
```

test command

```
for /f "tokrns=*" %%i ('findstr file1.txt file2.txt') do (set result=%%i)
```

Comment: Your question body does not ask a specific question and is off topic. Please fix it. I can tell you that the code you have written will not produce the expected result and that the expected result does not match the title. Please also open a Command Prompt window and enter `findstr /?` to find out how to use the `FindStr` command.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `file2.txt` is, essentially, a list of "configuration settings"... that is, a list of *name*-*value* pairs. Further, `file1.txt` is a list of *names* that you want to get the *values* of.

If that is the case, then you need to run the `findstr` command for *each* of the lines in `file1.txt`.  For instance:

**getvalues.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "REQUIRED=file1.txt"
set "SETTINGS=file2.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ( "%REQUIRED%" ) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%b in ( 'findstr /b "%%a=" "%SETTINGS%"' ) do (
        echo %%c
    )
)
```

produces the following:

```
C:\>getvalues.bat
c:\windows\aaa.dll
c:\windows\system32\ccc.dll
c:\windows\system32\drivers\ddd.sys
```

**Notes**

- I've hard-coded `REQUIRED` (the list of *names* to get *values* for) and `SETTINGS` (the list of *name*-*value* pairs). Depending on your requirements, you could take one or more from the command-line.
- The first loop runs over all lines in `REQUIRED` (=`file1.txt`). It uses `usebackq` because the filename is wrapped in double-quotes, just in case it contains spaces.
- For each *name* from the first loop (`%%a`), we run a `findstr` command. The `/b` tells it to look for the pattern at the beginning of the line. I also append an `=` to the end of the *name*. Both help prevent accidental partial-matches.
- The `tokens=1,* delims==` splits the output of `findstr` at the first (or only) equals-sign. The name (before the `=`) will be assigned to `%%b` and the value (all the rest) will be assigned to `%%c`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *compare* anything in order to get strings (that is, variable values) that have been *defined previously*:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the strings from file2.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (file2.txt) do set "%%a"

rem Retrieve the strings indicated in file1.txt
for /F %%a in (file1.txt) do echo !%%a!
```

If you insist in using the "find strings" way:

`for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /G:file1.txt file2.txt') do echo %%a`

Comment: Thank you so much for your support.